# Convert String data To char Array in Arduino

Tags: arduino-ide, http, json

I'm able to get json data and storing in String object, now i want to convert string into Char Array for parsing json data

I'm tried with this code, but it is not responding

```
      String data = http.getString();   //Get the request response payload
      Serial.println(data);                     //Print the response payload
      int len=data.length();
      Serial.println(len);  

      char  buf[len + 1];
      data.toCharArray(buf, len + 1);        
      int bufLength = sizeof(buf);
      Serial.println(bufLength);   //Printing nothing
```

Comment: Tried [`c_str()`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/string/functions/c_str/)?

Comment: No, can you tell me how it converts String JSON data to char Array

Comment: 1) Your code does work when I try it: all the `Serial.println()` do print their stuff. 2) It converts the `String` to a char array by giving you “direct access to the internal String buffer”. It's written in the doc I linked to.

Comment: for me, it is printing like this 
Exception (9):
epc1=0x40203d9e epc2=0x00000000 epc3=0x00000000 excvaddr=0x64522072 depc=0x00000000
after len

Comment: There is no need for char array. It's possible to access elements inside of String by `data[index]`. Or you can use [ArduinoJson](https://github.com/bblanchon/ArduinoJson) library

Comment: One of your problems is you don't know what sizeof does. I think you wanted to use strlen.